# How do you solve $I' = rI(S - I) - qI$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$
\frac{dI}{dt} = rI(S-I)-qI
$$

where $q, r, S$ are positive constants. I can solve it without the additional $qI$ term on the end, but I am not sure how to proceed when the right side is a difference with the variable in both terms. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can indeed solve it without the additional $qI$ term on the end, then hopefully this hint should work: $rI(S-I)-qI=rI((S-\frac{q}{r})-I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution
$$
J = \frac{1}{I}$$
Then 
$$
J' = -\frac{1}{I^2} I' = (q-r S) J + r
$$
This is a linear equation and can be solved easily